# Pass date year month slug in html template ajax post request

Tags: ajax, django, url, post

I have a blogost, comment and like model. The like model has a genericforeignkey field so I can link likes to blogposts and comments.

The view is working correctly however I am having trouble passing the parameters in the ajax request

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns =[
url(r'^$',views.home, name = 'home'),

url(r'^blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 
views.blog,
name = 'view_blogpost_with_pk'),

url(r'^blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/ajax/like/$',VotesView.as_view(model=BlogPost, vote_type=Like.LIKE),
       name='blog_like'),

url(r'^blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<day>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/ajax/dislike/$', VotesView.as_view(model=BlogPost, vote_type=Like.DISLIKE),
       name='blog_dislike'),
```

]

**blog.html**

```
    <ul>
      <li data-id="{{ like_obj.id }}" data-type="blog" data-action="like" title="Like">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
          <span data-count="like">{{ like_obj.votes.likes.count }}</span>
      </li>
      <li data-id="{{ like_obj.id }}" data-type="blog" data-action="dislike" title="Dislike">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
          <span data-count="dislike">{{ like_obj.votes.dislikes.count }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

And the javascript. Just including dislike, like is very similar

```
 <script>
 function dislike()
{
    var dislike = $(this);
    var type = dislike.data('type');
    var pk = dislike.data('id');
    var action = dislike.data('action');
    var like = dislike.prev();

$.ajax({
    url : '/home/blog/2017/10/1/git/ajax/dislike/',
    method : 'POST',
    data : { 'obj' : pk },

    success : function (json) {
        dislike.find("[data-count='dislike']").text(json.dislike_count);
        like.find("[data-count='like']").text(json.like_count);
    }
});

return false;
}
```

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('[data-action="like"]').click(like);
    $('[data-action="dislike"]').click(dislike);
});
 </script>
```

So at the moment this working great except when i replace url with

```
url: '{% url "home:blog_dislike" year=obj.year month=obj.month day=obj.date 
slug=obj.slug %}'
```

I get

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'blog_like' with keyword 
arguments '{'year': '', 'month': '', 'day': '', 'slug': ''}' not found. 1 
pattern(s) tried: ['home/blog/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<month>[0-9]{1,2})/(? 
P<day>[0-9]{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)/ajax/like/$']
```

**views.py**

```
def blog(request,year,month,day,slug):

if request.method == 'GET':

    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(date__year=year, date__month=month, date__day=day,slug=slug)

    form = BlogPostForm()
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(comment_body_id=blogpost).order_by('-date') #Link comments to blogpost // comment_body is foreignkey to blogpost model
    c = comments.count()


    args = {'bpost': blogpost,'form':form,'comments':comments,'c':c}
    return render(request,'home/blog.html',args)    

if request.method == 'POST':

    blogpost = BlogPost.objects.get(date__year=year, date__month=month, date__day=day,slug=slug)

    form = BlogPostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit = False)
        comment.comment_body = blogpost
        comment.save()
        text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        form = BlogPostForm()
        return redirect(request.build_absolute_uri())

else:
    form = BlogPostForm()

    args = {'form':form,'text':text}
    return render(request, 'home/blog.html', args)   



class VotesView(View):
    model = None  
    vote_type = None 



def post(self,request, year, month, day, slug):

    obj = self.model.objects.get(date__year=year, date__month=month, date__day=day,slug=slug)

    try:
        x = Like.objects.get(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj), object_id=obj.id, user=request.user)
        if x.vote is not self.vote_type:
            x.vote = self.vote_type
            x.save(update_fields = ['vote'])
            result = True
        else:
            x.delete()
            result = False
    except Like.DoesNotExist:   
        obj.votes.create(user=request.user, vote=self.vote_type) 
        result = True

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({
            "result": result,
            "like_count": obj.votes.likes().count(),
            "dislike_count": obj.votes.dislikes().count(),
            "sum_rating": obj.votes.sum_rating()
        }),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: is your js file in a seperate file?  where the variable `obj` comes from there `year=obj.year month=obj.month day=obj.date`? did you mean `like_obj`?

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yes in base.html i got the js. obj is the object i am getting in the view, either a blogpost or comment. Just to say this is working perfect just the url doesnt seem to work

Comment: Actually i see that you get from the view `like_obj` not `obj`....
add your context in your view

Comment: Got it working. Just added bpost.date.year, bpost.date.month,bpost.date.day, bpost.date.slug.. Thx for your help @Lemayzeur